# Skipping first character regex

Tags: regex

I'm currently using the following code to remove certain characters from a string in an array

```
myArray[x] = myArray[x].replaceAll("[aeiou]","");
```

which works fine, but I need to ignore the first character of the string so for example if an array element was Alan it would be stripped to Aln.

I'm not sure if using a replaceAll is the best way about doing it but the only other way I can think of is removing the first character, applying the above regex to the string, appending the character back on and then inserting back into the array, which seems a long winded way of doing it.

Comment: What regex engine are you using? Looks like Java? If so add that to the tags. Different engines support different features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative lookbehind to assert that the pattern is not preceded by the line start marker (`^`):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final String[] input = {"abe", "bae"};
    for(final String s: input) {
        System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?<!^)[aeiou]", ""));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ab
b
```

Answer (score 1):

What about something like ..

`myArray[x] = myArray[x].replaceAll("(^.)[aeiou]", "\\1");`

// upd

Negative lookbehind is your solution, like Boris answered.

Comment: If this is Java you need to use `\\1` otherwise this will not compile.